# Dropdownlist with images in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

just wanted to know how to create a dropdownlist in asp.net with images beside the text. Eg, text=> Japan, at the left hand side of the text there will be a image. 
Actually, I want to create a international language website by using the dropdownlist to change language. Thank

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/p/1421966/3157227.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[EasyListBox](http://www.easylistbox.com/demoCustomized.aspx) and [oabout](http://www.obout.com/combobox/) both seem rather good, although I've not either before.